# What do "not on my watch" and "not on my turf" stand for?

Tags: phrases

I deduce those mean "not on my field of interest" or "simply I don't care", are those correct?

Comment: To my understanding, these phrases mean the following.

"Not on my watch": I will not allow this to happen/take place while I am in charge.

"Not on my turf": I will not allow this to happen/take place on my property (house, land, ...).

Comment: "Not on my watch" almost certainly references the concept of "watch" used nautically and in the military, where a rotating group of people would each "serve watch" for 4-8 hour periods, throughout the day and night, being in charge of many of the goings-on within the crew being managed.  It simply means "I will not allow this while I am in charge."

Comment: (To restate)  The difference turns on a time/space distinction -- "watch" is (literal or metaphorical) **time**; "turf" is (literal or metaphorical) **space**.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The speaker is saying that they will not allow something to happen, and the intent is that they will be taking action to stop it.  The thing happening is most likely unusual and goes against the rules or status quo in some way.

> "Not on my watch": *(This thing) will not happen when I am on duty.*

A security guard is protecting a building. He sees someone breaking into a window and says to himself "nuh-uh, *not on my watch* buddy." Then goes off to apprehend the burglar.

> "Not on my turf": *(This thing) will not happen in my area.*

A drug dealer controls the drug trade in certain part of town. Learning that someone new is dealing drugs in his neighborhood he calls his gang together. He says to them

> "This can't continue to happen, *not on my turf*.  Let's go teach this guy a lesson."

Answer (score -3):

Nice explanations for both questions above; to simplify:

#### NOT ON MY WATCH

This comes from the old days of the "Wild West"; at night (no electricity) and you are all alone in a remote area with 3-4 buddies; so each one takes a turn to stay awake while the others are sleeping.

The others can sleep safe and sound with the sincere efforts of the guy whose turn is now to be "on the watch"; this guy now has to shoulder the responsibility of others who trust him that he will remain fully awake and alert in case bandits are sneaking up on them; so his philosophy is that

> "I will make sure that everyone is safe: nothing is going to happen on my watch".

In contrast, another fellow whose turn is now to be "on the watch" falls asleep; bandits sneak up and everyone gets injured; so such a person has failed in his or her duty.

In modern terminology, "not on my watch" refers to any person who has been given the task of being responsible for the safety of people and property and the environment: this can include parents, teachers, doctors, CEOs, leaders, Priests, Senators, Mayors and the President. When these people are elected by the voters, will they promise to deliver or will they simply dance "while Rome burns"?

#### NOT ON MY TURF

Has already been well explained above; "Turf" refers to your area of control or ownership; If you are a security Guard then your "Turf" is the shopping Mall that you have been hired to protect; so you are determined that

> no crime will occur "on my turf"

even though you do not physically own it, but by being employed by the company, you have a fiduciary duty to fulfill your employment contract "as if" that turf belongs to you.

In the 2nd case scenario, "not on my Turf" refers to your business that you own, your house or even your neighbourhood, where you take personal charge to ensure the safety of your family and staff, and safety of the neighbourhood kids from attempts by drug dealers to enter "your" turf.

Comment: To Adam:this is a good answer that only suffered from lack of formatting, which I've fixed by editing; please divide your answer into many short paragraphs for easier reading, and learn to highlight important sections by starting the sentence with the **>** sign.
 (To the 2 ***Reckless Anonymouse Downvoters***: *this is, I repeat,* **a GOOD answer**, so I HOPE YOU PROMPTLY REVERSES YOUR DOWNVOTE HERE!) To ELU members:please take care to **judge an answer by its content** not its formatting or downvotes, and be sure to avoid downvoting a good answer from a new user by **your** impatient error!

Comment: @EnglishStudent: your views on what constitute a good answer will never carry more weight than those of the downvoters. As long as your comments contain grammatical errors, they may carry less

Comment: @TimLymington: where are the grammatical errors, if you please?

Comment: @EnglishStudent This is not a good answer: it is just silly. The word "watch"  as used to describe a safety  duty (fire-watch, night watch) pre-dates the wild west by hundreds of years, and the word "turf" comes from old English. Also, there is nothing in the way of sources to substantiate the specious explanations of the phrases.

Comment: @Tim Lymington your words " your views on what constitute a good answer will never carry more weight than those of the downvoters" are alarming -- *Why should it carry **more weight** than any other person's opinion?* I am a member here and entitled to express my opinion in comments. I should also hope that the attitude of ELU members to an answer by a new user is **less dismissive** than those downvotes indicate. **Was one downvote yours?** Note 2: I REVISES every answer and comment at least twice before&after posting so you can be sure that any grammatical error was **strictly intentional!**

Comment: @Cascabel 'good answer' and 'correct answer' are rather different things, and I am no expert on whether it is a correct answer. **It does answer the question** and OP has not asked about etymology anyway. Since Adam is a very new user you should make allowance for the lack of references. **I am sure you didn't downvote it** -- however those who did probably did not have your clarity of vision, but downvoted based on the lack of formatting, I think; and were not gracious enough to explain why. If this answer gets many downvotes even after I improved the formatting, I shall accept your argument!

Comment: @EnglishStudent: If you instruct two other members to reverse their opinion of this poorly-researched answer, you ought to show some reason why you know better than they do.  Your poor grammar and spelling (whether intentional or not) make your views on English less valuable than most; shouting will not alter that.

Comment: @TimLymington I cannot imagine why you would say *"poor grammar and spelling (whether intentional or not) make your* [my] *views on English less valuable than most"* but your point on shouting is well taken: please be kind enough to ***forgive my enthusiastic writing style*** and mild belligerence in response to some of your assumptions -- but *you should not presume to know why they downvoted*, and neither will I. All other issues aside,the main impediment here for me to make any useful argument is that the 2 downvoters did not leave any explanation why **they think** it is not a good answer!

Comment: @EnglishStudent Why do cats lick their balls? Why do people downvote? Because they can. Asking others to reverse their votes... it's futile. Being familiar with your style of writing, I know you mean well. But for strangers on the internet, it'll mos def sound like you're shouting. :)

Comment: @NVZ my young sister (now 26 and not my *real* sister) used to be such an enthusiastic text messager (ending every sentence with an exclamation mark because she felt full stops made a texted sentence flat and expressionless) that **I developed a horror of 'flat' sentences** with ordinary full stops and *blocks of text without **bold** or italics.* I do take your point and that of the esteemed Tim Lymington (who is apparently **not familiar** with my writing style) that it can sound a bit LOUD amidst the DEAFENING SILENCE of the written word read -- I shall try for *a better balance* in future!

Comment: @EnglishStudent _In_ ___case___ you DIDN'T **know**. **;)**  https://www.lifewire.com/why-not-to-write-in-all-caps-1173242

Comment: @NVZ your point is well taken. It is tragic that my writing is already **so full of bold and** *italics* that when I want something to REALLY STAND OUT I am forced to use ALL CAPS! I am aware that all caps can be interpreted as shouting, but **forgot that fine nuance** when I used it in the earlier comment. On the other hand, I should have thought netizens would've learned by now *not to give too much importance to such things* -- we have been online on a mass scale now for **at least 12 years!**

Comment: Just for the record, I downvoted this answer because it's wrong.

Comment: @Hot Licks in that case **I do sincerely apologize** for misinterpreting your downvote as being a commentary on the lack of formatting! I also greatly appreciate your candid explanation here regarding the reason for the downvote. That is exactly why you are one of the members I like and respect the most here at EL & U.